# Problems in movinf forward and backward in spinner Android

Tags: android, spinner

I am building an android application in which I am using a spinner. When I click on a spinner element I am able to move on the next activity,but after clicking on the back button and clicking on the same spinner element I cant move on the activity associated with it. Can anyone please help me in solving this problem?

```
package com.example.ip101;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Second extends Activity {

    Spinner spinner;
    //Spinner spinner2;
    String end;
    int p;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.states_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                // your code here
                String text = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                end = text;
                 if(text.startsWith("Andaman"))
                  {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AndamanNicobar.class );
                    startActivity(i);   

                 }
                 if(text.startsWith("Andra"))
                  {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AndraPradesh.class );
                    startActivity(i);

                 }
}


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }



        });


        //System.out.println(end);



    }
```

Comment: reset your spinner in onResume()?

Comment: Can you please tell where to put the On resume in the code uploaded above.

Comment: When I get the time I will write up some code, but I really suggest reading up on the fundamentals of Android. It only gets more complex unfortunately